# Objective-c iOs Autosaving information when exiting a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am programming an ios app and would like to save information on exit of the view. I know how to go about saving the actual information but I'm not sure where I should put the code.

In android, there are methods like onPause() where I can run the save code to capture whenever someone leaves an activity. Is there something in obj-c like that?

Comment: You can do this in dealloc method in case of UIView, If it is a UIViewController, you can use view life cycle methods as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your logic for saving the state of the view in `viewWillDisappear`

I guess you have not gone through the View Life Cycle, here s one nice image which has captured the view life cycle events.

[image]

Reference : http://rdkw.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/